# Google Sheets XML import price from item

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the price for this item, https://www.midwayusa.com/product/1009418514?pid=418514. I found that the price is only ever found in the source under a script which has tons of information (Lines 155-157 of view-source:https://www.midwayusa.com/product/1009418514?pid=418514). How would I go about extracting just that price data of 39.99 and importing it into my google sheets? I currently have everything under //script imported but how would I go about narrowing it down? `=IMPORTXML("https://www.midwayusa.com/product/1009418514?pid=418514","//script")`

Answer (score 0):

copy the source link into an empty cell, for example `A2`, and type this formula into another  empty cell `=getprice(A2)`.

This Google sheet function automatically pulls prices from products on certain websites as well as some other random sites . You will receive instructions on a Google Doc with a small piece of code and a script ID. These will be easily copied and pasted into the "Apps Script" section of your Google Sheet by following the provided instructions.